# Sending an email with Python from a Protonmail account, SMTP library

Tags: python, email, smtplib, mime-mail

I am using apple mail app with protonmail-I have the bridge app. ([MacOS and Windows install here](https://protonmail.com/bridge/); [linux here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/protonmail-bridge/).)

After activating the bridge app, I tried to send an email with python by using smtp library and it does not work. Here is the code which I tried to run and failed me:

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP("127.0.0.1", portnumber)
server.login("mymail@protonmail.com", "my password")
server.sendmail(
    "mymail@protonmail.com",
    "receiver@protonmail.com",
    "hello")
server.quit()
```

The error message I receive:

smtplib.SMTPDataError: (554, b'Error: transaction failed, blame it on the weather: malformed MIME header line: 00')

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might help..

```
import smtplib 
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart 
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

port_number =1234
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'sender@protonmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'receiver@protonmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'My Test Mail '
message = 'This is the body of the mail'
msg.attach(MIMEText(message))
mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('localhost',port_number)
mailserver.login("sender@protonmail.com", "mypassword")
mailserver.sendmail('sender@protonmail.com','receiver@protonmail.com',msg.as_string())
mailserver.quit()
```

Comment: It is important to note that this will only work if you have the protonmail bridge software running on the machine that is running this script. You cannot simply enter your account password for the `mailserver.login()` line; you have to check the bridge application for the hashed (or pseudo?) password that is provided for your account.

Comment: Mayle small update of imports: `from email.mime.text import MIMEText` and `from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. It just gives me `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

Comment: @Cerin - The above code doesn't work because the protonmail bridge requires starttls().

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty new to this and was having some significant trouble.... until I just made the following tiny change:

Change the from lines to this:

```
import smtplib 
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

port_number =1234
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'sender@protonmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'receiver@protonmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'My Test Mail '
message = 'This is the body of the mail'
msg.attach(MIMEText(message))
mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('localhost',port_number)
mailserver.login("sender@protonmail.com", "mypassword")
mailserver.sendmail('sender@protonmail.com','receiver@protonmail.com',msg.as_string())
mailserver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This can currently be done in Ubuntu 22.04 with Proton Mail Bridge v3.7.1 (br-183) and tested with Python 3.10.11. The key difference with older answers is that Proton Mail Bridge now requires starttls().

The snippet below formats the **message and MIME headers manually with string formatting.** It's important to note, the smtp.login() method requires, as input, the username provided by the bridge. Open the app, and retrieve it under Mailbox details -> SMTP -> Username & Password.

```
import smtplib

msg = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % ('sender@protonmail.com', 'receiver@protonmail.com', 'automated: subject', 'automated: body')

with smtplib.SMTP('127.0.0.1', 1025) as smtp:
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login(<Proton Mail Bridge Username:str>, <Proton Mail Bridge Password:str>)
    smtp.sendmail('sender@protonmail.com', 'receiver@protonmail.com', msg)
```

If you would like to use the MIME formatter from `email.mime` use this:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'sender@protonmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'receiver@protonmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'automated: test with MIME classes'
body = 'automated: lorem ipsum dolor etc and such as.'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body))

with smtplib.SMTP('127.0.0.1', 1025) as smtp:
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login(<Proton Mail Bridge Username:str>, <Proton Mail Bridge Password:str>)
    smtp.sendmail('sender@protonmail.com', 'receiver@protonmail.com', msg.as_string())
```